# polymer-cli - getting "Can’t find variable: babelHelpers" when I set compile to true

Tags: polymer-2.x, polymer-cli

I use Polymer 2.0 and my build setting is:

```
"builds": [
{
  "name": "bundled",
  "bundle": true,
  "js": { "compile": true},
  "css": { "minify": true },
  "html": { "minify": true }
}]
```

I get "Can’t find variable: babelHelpers" error after build.

The Polymer CLI version that I use is 1.1.0.

EDIT: I was using polymer-cli locally. After installing latest polymer-cli globally, now I get “Constructor requires ‘new’ operator” on safari and “Failed to construct ‘HTMLElement’: Please use the ‘new’ operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.” on chrome.

EDIT2: used webcomponents-loader.js instead of webcomponents-lite.js and my problem solved.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with Polymer Starter Kit 2. Can you provide repro steps? Or a sample repo to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @tony19 I put a sample here: https://github.com/Homa/polyer2-test

Comment: Hmm. Still cannot reproduce. I'm on macOS Sierra, node 7.10.0, polymer-cli 1.1.0.

Comment: I recommend [re]running `npm install` or `yarn` to install your dependencies.

Comment: @tony19:  I was using polymer-cli locally. After installing latest polymer-cli globally, now I get “Constructor requires ‘new’ operator” in safari and “Failed to construct ‘HTMLElement’: Please use the ‘new’ operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.” in chrome.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting same error.  Problem was that `index.html` is technically my entrypoint in my `polymer.json` config, but my actual served up entrypoint is another file that comes from my server (`_Layout.cshtml` since I'm using .NET on my backend).  What I needed to do was take the code in my compiled `index.html` file and move it over to my CSHTML file once I set `"compile": true`.  Problem solved.

Comment: currently trying something similar. May i message you for help?

Comment: @EffGee I am by no means an expert, but if you join the Polymer slack channel at [polymer.slack.com](http://polymer.slack.com), the Polymer engineers are actually in the general channel and will answer questions! That's where I usually go :)