# BabelHelpers is not defined using Polymer

Tags: polymer, babeljs

I'm using Polymer and its build process. The bundled files are generated throughmy polymer.json file.

I'm not explicitely using Babel, I've just seen it's used by "paper-autocomplete".

When going to the website, I have a js error stating the BabelHelpers is not defined.

- When I use MAJ+F5, it works !
- When I use F5, it doesn't work
  (BabelHelpers is not defined)

When running it locally it works fine. When I deploy it to my server, I face this issue.

I'm running it as a standalone Java application as it has a Spring backend.
The website as multiple entry points, it works fine for all other ones.

**The stacktrace :**

[image: BabelHelpers]

**Command :**

```
polymer build --js-minify --css-minify --html-minify
```

**The polymer.json file**

```
{
  "entrypoint": "pt.html",
  "builds": [{
      "bundle": true,
      "js": {"compile": true, "minify": true},
      "css": {"minify": true},
      "html": {"minify": false},
      "addServiceWorker": true 
    }],
  "shell": "resources/elements-platform.html",
  "fragments": [
    "resources/html/lazy-resources.html",
    "resources/html/ym-dashboard.html",
    "resources/html/ym-partners.html",
    "resources/html/ym-favorite.html",
    "resources/html/ym-agenda.html",
    "resources/html/ym-todos.html",
    "resources/html/ym-profile.html",
    "resources/html/ym-messages.html",
    "resources/html/shop-list.html",
    "resources/html/shop-detail.html"
  ],
  "sources": [
   "resources/src/**/*",
   "resources/css/**/*",
   "resources/data/**/*",
   "resources/images/**/*",
   "resources/img/**/*",
   "resources/js/*",
   "resources/js/cal/*",
   "resources/js/countdown/*",
   "resources/bower.json"
  ],
  "extraDependencies": [
    "resources/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a few changes, but I don't know which one solved the issue. The problem came from paper-autocomplete. When I stopped using it I didn't have the issue anymore.
I'm still using it, but I made several changes :

- I made sure I was using the generated service-worker
- I stopped using the version of JQuery that was in my bower (3.2.1) and used it from JQuery CDN (2.3.1) as I've seen it caused issues sometimes
- Added manifest.json in the polymer.json file

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same issue few days ago after I updated Polymer-cli to newest version. But in my case my application throwed same error on local virtual host (with self-sign certificate). On production website it was fine.

Actually, babelHelpers are injected into file that is selected as `entrypoint` inside your `polymer.json` file. Maybe try to look there, if you have correct existing file.

there are few existing issues on github with this problem. Unfortunately there is no verified answer (Polymer team does not really care about github issues)

https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/issues/787
https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/issues/765

There is also same question on stackoverflow with answer:
[polymer-cli - getting "Can’t find variable: babelHelpers" when I set compile to true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44373210/polymer-cli-getting-can-t-find-variable-babelhelpers-when-i-set-compile-to)

Comment: Thank you, indeed I've seen those unresolved issues :(
I tried without the bundle version and have the same problem

Comment: @user2447161 maybe try to start your application without service workers. They are hardly chaching files nad CTRL+F5 deletes it for current session but if you hit only f5 service worker can be installed back with previous version of cached files (their behaviour is really strange and i didn't ever get it)

Answer (score 1):

I too am seeing `'babelHelpers' is undefined`. In my case it's coming from redux.js:

```
q='object'==('undefined'===typeof self?'undefined':babelHelpers
.typeof(self))&&self&&self.Object===Object&&self,r=p||q||
Function('return this')(),s=r.Symbol,t=Object.prototype,
```

[image: F12 Console error in IE11]

Babel helpers is also raised as in [Issue #606](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/issues/606), which says that it's resolved and closed. But it or something similar is back.

Comment: Hello. So did you removed redux.js or did you find a proper solution?

Comment: @user2447161 My problem went away with yesterday's update of the Polymer CLI to 1.5.7. I'm using `polymer build` to create an ES5 code bundle.